# filename based file types in LightTable

Tags: vagrant, lighttable

When using vagrant you define a file `Vagrantfile` which defines your machines.  This file is basically ruby so I would like to open it as a ruby file in LightTable.

Presumably it's not possible to add a filename match to something like `:lt.objs.files/file-types`?  Is this a possible future feature?  Is there any way to 'open as'?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup custom filetypes; [see here](https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/362#issuecomment-35671560) for more.

```
{:+ {:files [(:lt.objs.files/file-types [{:name "Wisp",
                                          :exts [:wisp],
                                          :mime "text/x-clojurescript",
                                          :tags [:editor.wisp]})]}}
```

However, I don't think this will work with a file without an extension; you'd have to tell Light Table to treat all files with no extension as Ruby, and you probably work with more than just `Vagrantfile` without a file extension.